# railsでの日本語URLエンコード問題

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

現在、railsで開発したサイトで日本語URLを利用しています。
facebookの共有URLをrequest.urlで生成しているのですが、
下記のエラーが出てしまい、うまく動きません。

> incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

多くのサイトで下記の方法で解決していたのですが

```
request.url.force_encoding("utf-8")
```

記述忘れを防ぐためにも、毎回`force_encoding("utf-8")`を用いてエンコードせずに
`request.url`のメソッド自体をオーバーライドしてエンコードしたいと考えています。

どのようにすれば既存の`request.url`のメソッドをオーバーライドできるでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

アラウンドエイリアスというテクニックを使えば実現は可能です。
以下のコードをlib配下に置くなりして、Rails起動時に読み込むようにしてみてください。
（rails 4.2.3で確認）

```
class ActionDispatch::Request
  alias_method :__url, :url
  def url
    __url.force_encoding("utf-8")
  end
end
```

requestのurlメソッドを別名で退避してから、新urlメソッドでエンコードしたURLを返します。

ただし、元々urlメソッドを呼び出していた箇所（Rails内も含め！）の挙動が変わる可能性があるので、そこは注意してください。（ひょっとしたら何か不都合があるかも）

facebookの共有URLを生成する箇所が分かっているなら、素直にエンコード済みURLを返すようなヘルパーを作った方が無難だと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございました！！！
ヘルパーメソッドで対応して、見事にエラーが飛んでこなくなりました！！